# Looking for spring data jpa query for findall excluding some names from a column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

| list_Type_code(PK) | ListTypeName |
| --- | --- |
| CONTRACT | cpn |
| CPN | formul |
| PRP |  |

It's a get all endpoint.I need a query to retrieve all data excluding certain names like CPN from column listtypecode.

Finally,It worked this way:
Page findAllByListTypeCodeNotIn(Collection listTypeCodeToExclude, Pageable pageable);

Comment: If you want to use a JPQL query, you need to show the entities. It would also be nice to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try to provide more data, as this is too little elaboration of your problem. Check the guide here: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you have to write a native query in JPA like below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from {table_name} where {column_name} not in :names}))
List<{entity_name}> findAllByName(@Param("names")Collection<String> names);
```

Please resolve placeholders accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple approach:**

```java
public List<ModelData> findByListTypeCodeNotIn(List<String> codes);
```

**We can use the above specified JPA query naming convention to achieve the desired result.**

Comment: Answers that only include code are not encouraged. Please, add some explanation about your answer and, if possible, a link to a source/documentation.